# display image on mouseover in windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project in c# using windows forms.
me and the group I am in want to make it so that when the user hovers their mouse over an image, in our case a card, that a larger image of that card appears next to the mouse arrow, much in the same way a tool tip would work.
I don't think you can use a tool tip to do this i have tried looking everywhere,
any advice or examples would be great thank you very much

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want to look at this [Code Project Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/ToolTip_With_Image.aspx)

It shows you how to create an [OwnerDrawn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw.aspx) ToolTip with an Image.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the responses I got everything figured out.
What I wanted to do was that when I moused over a certain area a different image for that area would popup in the same way that a tool tip did. So after some research I figured out how to create my own tool tip class.

here's an example.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CustomToolTip tip = new CustomToolTip();
        tip.SetToolTip(button1, "text");
        tip.SetToolTip(button2, "writing");
        button1.Tag = Properties.Resources.pelican; // pull image from the resources file
        button2.Tag = Properties.Resources.pelican2;       
    }
}

class CustomToolTip : ToolTip
{
    public CustomToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Popup += new PopupEventHandler(this.OnPopup);
        this.Draw +=new DrawToolTipEventHandler(this.OnDraw);
    }

    private void OnPopup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e) // use this event to set the size of the tool tip
    {
        e.ToolTipSize = new Size(600, 1000);
    }

    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e) // use this to customzie the tool tip
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;

        // to set the tag for each button or object
        Control parent = e.AssociatedControl;
        Image pelican = parent.Tag as Image;

        //create your own custom brush to fill the background with the image
        TextureBrush b = new TextureBrush(new Bitmap(pelican));// get the image from Tag

        g.FillRectangle(b, e.Bounds);
        b.Dispose();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do is to hide/show a picture box at specified location. Another method is to load & draw (paint) an image using `GDI` API.