# Replacing ToolTip Text with a GIF

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on redesigning an older application to make it more user-friendly. One addition I would like to make is, when hovering over a specific button, a ~(200, 200) demonstrative GIF appears to the bottom right of the cursor (similar to the functionality of a ToolTip).

I looked into the modification of the ToolTip class, which seems excessive. The above mentioned would be ideal, though I am considering a static imageBox that appears after a hovering for 2 or so seconds.

Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [display image on mouseover in windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8264340/display-image-on-mouseover-in-windows-form)

Comment: hidden ImageBox or Panel seems like the easiest and least code needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this article, it details out the steps of the image in a tooltip https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42050/ToolTip-With-Image-C

And this method in particular:

```
void CustomizedToolTip_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
{
        e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
        myToolTipRectangle.Size = e.Bounds.Size;
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBorderBrush, myToolTipRectangle);
        myImageRectangle = Rectangle.Inflate(myToolTipRectangle, 
                -BORDER_THICKNESS, -BORDER_THICKNESS);
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBackColorBrush, myImageRectangle);
        Control parent = e.AssociatedControl;
        Image toolTipImage = parent.Tag as Image; 
        if (toolTipImage != null)
        {
            myImageRectangle.Width = myInternalImageWidth;
            myTextRectangle = new Rectangle(myImageRectangle.Right, myImageRectangle.Top,
            (myToolTipRectangle.Width - myImageRectangle.Right - BORDER_THICKNESS), 
                        myImageRectangle.Height);
            myTextRectangle.Location = 
        new Point(myImageRectangle.Right, myImageRectangle.Top);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(myBackColorBrush, myTextRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(toolTipImage, myImageRectangle);
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, myFont, 
            myTextBrush, myTextRectangle, myTextFormat);
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, myFont, 
            myTextBrush, myImageRectangle, myTextFormat);
        }
}
```