# Create Windows Forms(C#) tooltip that plays animated GIF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I am trying to show GIFs when the user hovers over certain icons on a Windows Forms application.  The GIFs must be shown outside the actual area of the form with the perfect solution looking like a tooltip with IsBallon set to True that perfectly wraps around the GIF.

After modifying the solution in a similar question [Replacing ToolTip Text with a GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542839/replacing-tooltip-text-with-a-gif) I was able to render just an image inside of a tooltip.  This will not however animate the GIF for whatever reason and my attempts to step through the frames of the GIF have so far failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this on a search result form. Hovering over the image would pop-up a larger version of the same image. It was done by creating a form with a Dock.Fill PictureBox during the MouseEnter event of the icon/image. I saved the new PictureBox in the Tag property of the original icon/image. On MouseLeave I just disposed of the form and PictureBox.

Here's my code, modify to suit your needs:

```
    void pb_MouseEnter( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        // sender was my original image. You may need to perform type checks
        PictureBox pb = ((PictureBox)sender);
        // Ignore empty images
        if (pb.Image == null)
            return;

        Form f = new Form();
        f.ControlBox = false;
        f.Enabled = false;
        f.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;

        // Modify to suit your location
        f.Location = new Point( pb.TopLevelControl.Location.X + pb.Location.X - f.Width - 25, MousePosition.Y - f.Height / 2 );

        f.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        f.Size = new System.Drawing.Size( 300, 256 );
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        f.TopMost = true;

        PictureBox pb2 = new PictureBox();
        pb2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        pb2.Image = (Image)pb.Image.Clone();
        pb2.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
        f.Controls.Add( pb2 );

        pb.Tag = pb2;
        f.Show();
        this.Focus();
    }

    void pb_MouseLeave( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        PictureBox pb = ((PictureBox)sender);
        if (pb.Tag != null)
        {
            PictureBox pb2 = (PictureBox)pb.Tag;
            Form f = (Form)pb2.Parent;
            pb2.Dispose();
            f.Dispose();
            pb.Tag = null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Works good but to actually get the GIF to run I had to run it on another thread. The following did the trick... 
`System.Threading.Tasks.Task t = new System.Threading.Tasks.Task(() 
    => 
   pb.Image = sourceGif);
t.Start();`